# Changing a for each loop to a for loop and while loop

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

How do I rewrite this as a while loop and as a for loop?

```
public void invertPicture()
{
  Pixel[] pixelArray = getPixels();

  for(Pixel p : pixelArray){
    p.setRed(255-p.getRed());
    p.setGreen(255-p.getGreen());
    p.setBlue(255-p.getBlue());
  }
}
```

Comment: In which programming language? Is this Java?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't remember Java now. But, the official documentation (did) describe foreach in terms of for.

Comment: Oh, and you should add a Java tag to your question so a Java guru can find.

Comment: Smells like homework.

Comment: Why  do you want to re-write this? Very easy to do, just doesn't make much sense, unless this is a homework question, in which case you should try it yourself.

Comment: It is a homework question, I am required to make this in the form of a for loop and a while loop.

Comment: How do you suppose it was done before for-each was invented??

Comment: "in the form of a for loop and a while loop" - Hopefully not both simultaneously.  You can do a for-each using `for`, and you can do a `for` with `while`.  `while` is effectively the "most primitive" of the three and hence the others can be reduced to that.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for your homework:

```
for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; ++i) {
  myArray[i].doSomething();
}
```

I leave the while as an exercise, it is very similar: declare i outside the loop, increment i within the loop.

Comment: This is as much of a hint as the OP should hope for.  If he understands programming at all it's more than enough.

Answer (score -2):

Well, your code is already in a for loop. However, I will show you another way to do a for loop and a while loop.

For Loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < pixelArray.length; i++){
     pixelArray[i].setRed(255 -pixelArray[i].getRed());
     pixelArray[i].setGreen(255 - pixelArray[i].getGreen());
     pixelArray[i].setBlue(255 - pixelArray[i].getBlue());
}
```

While Loop:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < pixelArray.length){
     i++;
     pixelArray[i].setRed(255 -pixelArray[i].getRed());
     pixelArray[i].setGreen(255 - pixelArray[i].getGreen());
     pixelArray[i].setBlue(255 - pixelArray[i].getBlue());
}
```

Also: A For Loop is just a easier to implement while loop.